# using FTS3 in android

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I have an `android` application that contains 6 tables and pre populated ( contains data) each table contains at least 5000 records , and i want to support `FTS3` , i understand that it's faster than regular `SQLite` tables . now should i convert these table schema to use `FTS3` 
example :

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TABLE_1 USING fts3( col1, col2 ,....)
```

for each table of these 6 tables ? or i need to make a sperate table for each table and insert 
the same records in the `fts3` tables ???

Answer (score 1):

FTS tables are not efficient for 'normal' queries, so it is likely that you still need your original tables.

FTS tables can be prepopulated just like normal tables.

If you decide to keep the original tables, you can save space by using *contentless* or *external content* FTS tables (see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2)).